# How to extract data separated by a semicolon

Tags: sql-server, csv, substring

Lets say I have a table in SQLServer named Tasks. It contains some tasks with people assigned to tasks. Workers are in one column. They are separated by semicolon.

```
ID  Workers
1   John Newman; Troy Batchelor; Mike Smith
2   Chris Portman
3   Sara Oldman; Greg House
```

I need to separate workers from column like below

The result:

```
ID  Worker
1   John Newman
1   Troy Batchelor
1   Mike Smith
2   Chris Portman
3   Sara Oldman
3   Greg House
```

I have no idea what to do.
Do I have to use some procedure or simple query is enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: Always search the internet first, before posting a question. String splitting is one of the most common questions. The better answer is to fix your schema and properly normalize your tables.

Answer (score 3):

i solved your problem without using any function or stored procedure

```
SELECT ID,Workers FROM tblSemiColon


SELECT ID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Workers
FROM
(
SELECT ID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Workers,';','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   tblSemiColon
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

[image]

this will work across all the version of sql server..i had tested it....

you can reduce the size of varchar length..

Answer (score 1):

If you are on sql-server 2016 or higher you can use  STRING_SPLIT function

```
SELECT id,  value  
FROM Tasks
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Workers, ';')
```